# Docusign - EnvelopesAPI query

Tags: docusignapi

We have a developer account and I am starting to integrate it into our system. The system is based on Laravel/VueJS and I've 2 additions Eric Tucker Docusign SDK and the official Docusign SDK.

I want to create quick views on our system for envelopes, so Action Required, Waiting for others, Expiring soon, Completed and Authentication failed. BUT, when I retrieve all the envelopes, I can't see what status the envelope is (for eg: Waiting for others)

Once I've returned all the envelopes, which additonal APIs will return that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve envelope status you'll need to use the listStatusChanges method in the PHP SDK. Here is a small snippet of code I put together based on an example in a controller on our [PHP MVC launcher](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Controllers/Examples/eSignature/EG003ListEnvelopes.php):

```
$config = new Configuration();
$config->setHost($args['base_path']);
$config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);    
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
$envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

$from_date = date("c", (time() - (10 * 24 * 60 * 60)));
$options = new ListStatusChangesOptions();
$options->setFromDate($from_date);
try {
$results = $envelope_api->listStatusChanges($args['account_id'], $options);
} catch (ApiException $e) {
var_dump($e);
}
```

This block of code should give you envelope status changes for envelopes in the past 10 days. Be sure to use ISO 8601 date format on the date query parameters.